# Can't boot into GUI after removing Ubuntu Desktop to get pure Lubuntu

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I followed the instructions at [this site](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntucat/?s=pure%20lubuntu) to get pure Lubuntu. Unfortunately, after doing so my computer will no longer boot into the GUI. I'm able to switch over to a terminal just fine, but the GUI never comes up. The computer boots past the Lubuntu splash screen and then displays:

```
apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName 
* Starting web server apache2
etc/rc2.d/S99acpi-support: line 7: /usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs: No such file or directory
```

It seems to be stuck there. Yesterday, I let the computer run for 24 hours. When I came back, the whole screen was full of code. I didn't catch any of it though.

I attempted to restart from a Live USB, but the computer wouldn't even recognize it. I tried it in every port but I can't get it to show up on the boot menu.

I was able to Ctrl+Alt+F6 to a terminal. I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop
```

I also tried `sudo apt-get install -f`.

None of this helped. Now it's just back to the aforementioned apache2 error message.

Another oddity: I can reboot the computer from the terminal using `sudo reboot` but when I attempt `sudo shutdown now` it pumps out a ton of error messages, switches to single user mode, and waits for a command.

How can I get my GUI back?

**Update:**

I realized that I was stupidly trying to boot a computer with UEFI using an x86 USB. It boots from a live USB using the 64-bit live USB.

Comment: One of the first things that guide says is that the scripts may uninstall a bunch of packages that you need for other software, but you're responsible for identifying them and writing them down for reinstall later.  

I don't know how, but you should fish out a log of the package changes you made somehow, and track down those non-ubuntu related packages.

Comment: Take a look at this[Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/329318/cant-restart-apache-2/329379#329379), see if it helps.

Comment: @Mitch No change

Comment: Are you sure `etc/rc2.d/S99aspci-support: line 7: /usr/share/aspci-support/power-funcs: No such file or directory` is not a typo? Watch the `aspci` instead of `acpi`, I think  correcting that would help? Maybe `shutdown now` gives error because of acpi-support is messed up?

Comment: @EliahKagan I have not found the answer to the main thrust of the question: the GUI won't boot. The only thing I figured out was that I was stupidly trying to boot from a USB with the wrong USB. I still don't have the GUI back when I take the USB out. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: @Samik aspci was a typo. It was just apci.

Comment: I'm not sure how painful this would be, but you could always reinstall Lubuntu from the Live USB. Of course, make backups first, and copy anything modified that is not in `~`.

Comment: @jimirings Well, maybe I'm pinching here too much but it's `acpi` not `apci`,this pinch is specially when there is an error message like `no such file or directory` :D

Comment: @Samik I don't know why I can't read/type that correctly, but it is acpi, as you say it should be.

Comment: @jimirings, ok then try starting with the kernel parameter `acpi=off`, to pass the parameter to Linux kernel, press `e` in grub screen while the Ubuntu option is highlighted, to edit kernel line, then append that parameter to the end of the line that starts with `linux`.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible you removed the lightdm, which is the login window. This is what gets you into any flavor of Ubuntu, its where you login. Try reinstalling this. And, the apache2 has nothing to do with this problem, thats a whole nother problem completely. You most likely removed as well, many key files...I would back up your files using a live boot and re-install lubuntu, purely...

Comment: No luck reinstalling lightdm. And yes, I could wipe the computer and start from scratch, but I'd really like to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: If they are getting the Lubuntu splash screen, they are probably going past the lightdm stage okay.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, type-

```
startx
```

maybe it brings up the GUI

Comment: If the above doesnt work, as a workaround I could suggest installing all the packages that you uninstalled, so that you could at least get your Ubnutu GUI back.

Comment: No luck with startx. And reinstalling all the packages that I uninstalled is somewhat counterproductive. I'd rather just find the specific thing that's causing the problem and fix *that*.

Comment: ok..takes a lot of patience to do that!